# On Outer Approximation of Lebesgue Measurable Sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I have two questions, the first is based on [Q: Royden Chapter 2, Theorem 11](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597024/q-royden-chapter-2-theorem-11).

1. In the book, it is said "Now consider the case that $m^*(E) = \infty$. Then, $E$ can be expressed as the disjoint union of a countable collection $\{E_k\}$ of measurable sets, each of which has finite measure." I know why already. However, why is the word "Then" there? It might suggest that the statement is true because of the fact that the outer measure of $E$ is infinity, but it is not true because we can do the same thing with finite case, right? Or am I missing something? If I am right, I mean the word "Then" should not be there (better change it with "Observe" or something haha). For now, the way I understand the proof is that we can actually assume any measurable $E$ (not necessarily of finite/infinite outer measure) and work the argument out to arrive at something that deals with finite outer measure. Hopefully anyone can correct me, if any.
2. I wonder about this equivalence in $\mathbb{R}^n$. What is the idea to show the direction that measurable $E$ can be approximated from the outside? I can only imagine the $R$ case as in no.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $E$ has infinite measure, it causes issues with the proof given for the finite case since it is not true that
   $$m^{\star}(O \setminus E) = m^{\star}(O) - m^{\star}(E) < \epsilon$$
   because you can't subtract an infinite quantity from both sides of the inequality.

   Therefore, we use the fact that the measure is $\sigma$-finite to break $E$ down into a countable sum of finite sets so we can use the finite argument.

   (The word 'then' is used in the proof to mean "In that case, ...")
2. The argument in $R^{d}$ is exactly the same. You can find a sequence of open boxes* $(B_{i})_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ such that $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} m(B_{i}) \leq m^{\star}(E) + \epsilon$ and then take their union to obtain an open set $O$ satisfying
   $$m^{\star}(O) \leq m^{\star}(E) + \epsilon$$

   *Here a box is an "d-dimensional interval" $B = \prod_{j = 1}^{d} I_{j}$ where each $I_{j}$ is an interval.

Comment: 2. I see. So, you mean we can also deal with the case $E$ has infinite measure using similar arguments? What would be the disjoint collection $E_k$ here? It cannot be $E \cap$ (something like $d$-box of sides [k,k+1)) each right?

Comment: 1. Hence, if I arrange the proof from the start like: "Let $E$ be an arbitrary measurable space. Then $E$ can be expressed as disjoint countable union of measurable sets $E_k$ of finite measure. Consider an arbitrary $E_k$. Then (argue the rest similarly as in finite measure case in the original proof)", what do you think? I mean, if I understand your answer, then the infiniteness is still not used at all, right?

Comment: Yeah, we typically take $\bigcup_{n= 1}^{\infty} \: [-n, n]^{d}$ but that works too.

Comment: That's a perfectly fine to work the proof, as long as the measure space is $\sigma$-finite of course. (A lot of proofs in measure theory require reducing down to the finite case and then using the $\sigma$-finiteness in this way because infinite measures can cause issues.)

Comment: Thanks. It's just a little bit confusing when I saw the infinity sign but not used at all.